# How to render pug file dynamically instead of using the static angular-cli index.html?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, pug, angular-cli

I have an angular 2 application and I need to render **index.pug** instead of using the static **index.html** of angular-cli.

So what's the best practice for such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after googling a lot without any luck, I came up with the following workaround:

- In **angular-cli.json** change `"index": "index.html"` to `"index": "index.pug"`
- Rename **index.html** to **index.pug** and change its content to be **pug** content.
- In **index.pug** you should have two comments where you want to put your styles and script as the following:

  ```
  head
    // the next comment is important to replace with styles.
    //- styles
  body
    app-root Loading...
    // the next comment is important to replace with scripts.
    //- scripts
  ```
- Create parse-index.js in your root and put the following code:

  ```
  'use strict';

  const fs = require('fs');

  const INDENT = '    ';

  const INDEX = './dist/index.pug';

  let index = fs.readFileSync(INDEX);
  index = index.toString()
    .replace(/<(\s+)?head(\s+)?>|<(\s+)?\/(\s+)?head(\s+)?>/g, '');

  let linkPattern = /<(\s+)?link[^<>]+\/?(\s+)?>/g;

  let links = index.match(linkPattern);

  let scriptPattern = /<(\s+)?script[^<]+<(\s+)?\/(\s+)?script(\s+)?>/g;

  let scripts = index.match(scriptPattern);

  index = index.replace(linkPattern, '');
  index = index.replace(scriptPattern, '');

  scripts.forEach((script, index) => {
    scripts[index] = script.replace(/<|>.+/g, '').replace(/\s/, '(') + ')';
  });

  links.forEach((link, index) => {
    links[index] = link.replace(/<|\/(\s+)?>(.+)?/g, '')
      .replace(/\s/, '(') + ')';
  });

  index = index.replace(
    /\/\/(\s+)?-?(\s+)?scripts/g, scripts.join('\n' + INDENT)
  );

  index = index.replace(/\/\/(\s+)?-?(\s+)?styles/g, links.join('\n' + INDENT));

  fs.writeFileSync(INDEX, index);
  ```
- Finally, in **postinstall** in **package.json** put this: `ng build --prod && node parse-index.js`

I wish if someone introduce a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this manual](https://medium.com/@Ai_boy/configure-angular-2-cli-webpack-beta-14-5a7052ce6156), you can override angular-cli webpack config.